# jQuery toggle show/hide, how to show nested divs

Tags: jquery, html, toggle

I forked this script from jsfiddle for a contact page I'm making.  Problem is: I can't figure out how to show nested divs, which is required for a shortcode I will be using.

In my example, I created an ID called 'I need to be seen!' that I would like to see popup when the user clicks a face --  [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ninocodes/D8QsL/)

Here is the jQuery script I'm using:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#upload_page a").click(function(){
     var id =  $(this).attr('id');
     id = id.split('_');
     $(this).addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');
     $("#upload_container div").hide();
     $("#upload_container #upload_"+id[1]).show();
  });
});
```

Thanks!

Comment: why your jQuery is warped in Quotes `'` ??

Comment: First time using stackoverflow, I thought the backticks ' ' were required for formatting.  Thank you for the clarification!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the selector `#upload_container div` applies the style and actions to all divs inside `upload_container` instead you need to limit it to the children of `upload_container`

So

```
#upload_container > div {
    display:none;
}
```

then

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#upload_page a").click(function () {
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        id = id.split('_');
        $(this).addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');
        $("#upload_container > div").hide();
        $("#upload_container #upload_" + id[1]).show();
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/r82Bd/)

Another solution is to add a class to target the the `upload_*` elements like

```
    <div id="upload_bob9" class="upload"> Some Text 9
        <div class="nested_div">I need to be seen!</div>
    </div>
```

then

```
#upload_container .upload {
    display:none;
}
```

and

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#upload_page a").click(function () {
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        id = id.split('_');
        $(this).addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');
        $("#upload_container .upload").hide();
        $("#upload_container #upload_" + id[1]).show();
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/5WXjm/)

Note: **ID of an element must be unique** so use class attribute for `nested_div`

Comment: Arun, your first solution works like a charm.  Thank you for taking the time.

Answer (score 0):

Write:

```
$("#upload_page a").click(function(){
    var id =  $(this).attr('id');
    id = id.split('_');
    $(this).addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');
    $("#upload_container div").hide(); 
    $("#upload_container #upload_"+id[1]+",#upload_container #upload_"+id[1]+" *").show();
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/D8QsL/1/)

OR:

Add a class to all upload divs and hide them instead of hiding all div elements.

```
$("#upload_page a").click(function(){
    var id =  $(this).attr('id');
    id = id.split('_');
    $(this).addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');
    $("#upload_container .container").hide(); 
    $("#upload_container #upload_"+id[1]).show();
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/D8QsL/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Add this line `$("#upload_container #upload_"+id[1]).find('div').show();` in your code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#upload_page a").click(function(){
      var id =  $(this).attr('id');
      id = id.split('_');
      $(this).addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');
      $("#upload_container div").hide(); 
      $("#upload_container #upload_"+id[1]).show();
      $("#upload_container #upload_"+id[1]).find('div').show();
   });
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sesubash/D8QsL/3/) 
Hope it helps.